# SAS proc compare, 2 versions of the same table

Tags: sas, compare, comparison

I have two tables, version 1 and version n of the same dataset. The data can be in any format. I need to compare these tables, and find out the rows and values, which are different. There could be additional rows in the new tables.
My code:

```
proc compare
base=dk_upd 
compare=dk_old 
out=compare_test 
outall
OUTNOEQUAL 
allobs .
;
run;
```

Tried various options, couldn't find the needed combination

Comment: Have you tried outdiff?

Comment: yes, i tried, but it shows me the row (i suppose obs = row) that has the same values in both tables and it seems strange to me. Mb i dont understand the logics.

Comment: okay then you should use , oucomp and outbase as well, it will give you records from both the datasets to analyse

Comment: Suggest you add some sample data to your question. A few rows of data for each of the two datasets to be compared, and the desired output.

Comment: I managed to do it, but now i have another problem: I have more than 100 columns, and difference could be in any of them. how can I mark exact column with difference?